# Object initialization strategy for related objects

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

The scenario I'm working is the next: There's a Base (non-abstract) class that has several classes that inherit from it.
Based on a type I have to create one or another, my initial code is like this:

```
switch (type)
{
    case BaseType.Standard:
        _list.Add(Standard.Create(<params>)));
        break;
    case BaseType.Special:
        _list.Add(Special.Create(<params>));
        break;
}
```

[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRnNS.png)

Switch statement was simplified. Each specialization of the base class, has it's own initialization params, meaning that the client class is having a lot of params to cover for all the possible params to initialize each object from the child classes (or the base class itself).
I was wondering if someone could help me to figure a better way of initializing each of the classes (both childs and base). I was thinking in something like Abstract Factory design pattern, but I'm not so sure if it fits my use case.

I don't want to start having a huge switch statement per each type I need to initialize nor a method with a huge parameter list.

Minimal reproducible scenario:

```
public class Client
{
    public Client(int clientProperty)
    {
        ClientProperty = clientProperty;
    }

    public int ClientProperty { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BaseType> BaseTypes { get; set; } = new List<BaseType>();

    public BaseType CreateBase(BaseTypeEnum type, string paramA, int paramB, int paramC, string paramD, string paramE, int paramF)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case BaseTypeEnum.Base:
                return new BaseType(paramA);
            case BaseTypeEnum.Colored:
                return new ColoredBaseType(paramA, paramB, paramC);
            case BaseTypeEnum.Special:
                return new SpecialBaseType(paramA, paramD, paramE, paramF);
            default:
                return new BaseType(paramA);
        }
    }
}

public enum BaseTypeEnum
{
    Base,
    Colored,
    Special
}

public class ColoredBaseType : BaseType
{
    public ColoredBaseType(string paramA, int paramB, int paramC) 
        : base(paramA)
    {
        ParamB = paramB;
        ParamC = paramC;
    }

    public int ParamB { get; set; }
    public int ParamC { get; set; }
}

public class SpecialBaseType : BaseType
{
    public SpecialBaseType(string paramA, string paramD, string paramE, int paramF) : base(paramA)
    {
        ParamD = paramD;
        ParamE = paramE;
        ParamF = paramF;
    }

    public string ParamD { get; set; }
    public string ParamE { get; set; }
    public int ParamF { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You might try showing more code to better explain what you are talking about (say a simplified [mcve]). I'm having a hard time visualizing what you are talking about

Comment: I've added a UML diagram, hope it helps @Flydog57

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *I don't want to start having a huge switch statement* -- If a class has a "huge" number of inheritors there's probably something wrong with using the pattern in the first place. What makes you choose inheritance here? The code is too abstract to see if it's really necessary.

Comment: There's not much more than that, the inheritance is because each of the child classes is a specialization of the base Type. Each child provides different ways of calculating it price, it's UoM (unit of meassurement) among other things that makes each type a specialization of the base. I wanted to keep it abstract because I want to understand the options that I have to go with a different approach

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/421733/dry-polymorphic-object-creation-always-valid) would be helpfu.